# UIImage in SwiftUI SceneView

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit

I'd like to convert a UIImage to a 3D object in SceneView. I've found the following code example, which should work, but results in nothing showing up. The resource "placeholder" is just a random PNG image.

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct TestScene: View {
    
    var cameraNode: SCNNode? {
        let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane())
        node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "placeholder")
        return node
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        SceneView(
            scene: SCNScene(),
            pointOfView: cameraNode,
            options: []
        )
    }
    
}

struct TestScene_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestScene()
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Xcode]

Edit: Tested a variation of this code with a sample SCNScene, and it works! But I need to figure out how to convert a UIImage to the material in an empty SCNScene with SwiftUI.

[image]

Comment: Is your optional chaining working? I mean, are `geometry` and `firstMaterial` defined, or are they nil?

Comment: That might be why. I honestly have no idea. I just took the code from this answer, but it doesn't contextualise how it should be implemented. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49451321/15072454

Comment: You could set up a couple if/let instead of using optional chaining to check whether or not those properties are defined. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I could try that. I think the main issue is that the Node is seemingly never attached to the Scene. In this question they attach it as a childNode, but I can't tell what they're attaching it to, and can't get it working with my setup. https://stackoverflow.com/q/63921221/15072454

Comment: Yeah, you're actually loading an *empty* `SCNScene` into the `SceneView`, so you'll get nothing but a blank screen. You'll need to implement an `SCNScene`, then add whatever nodes to that scene and load that same instance into your `SceneView`. I know nothing about SceneKit (I'm into SpriteKit) but it's the same concept.

Comment: That's what I thought. Unfortunately I can only find examples/documentation on using SwiftView with already defined scenes (USDZ files). There's seemingly nothing on actually creating a scene for SwiftUI's SceneView

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general-purpose example of how I solved it.
Note that "placeholder" is the name of an image (PNG) from the project's XCAssets.

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct Augment: View {
    
    var scene: SCNScene? {
        let myScene = SCNScene()
        let node = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane())
        node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "placeholder")
        myScene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
        return myScene
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        SceneView(scene: scene)
    }
    
}
```

[image: PreviewProvider]